# Issues making a DLL that replaces function calls from a system library

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm trying to make a fake opengl32.dll on Windows to capture OpenGL calls. When I put the DLL in the same directory as a simple OpenGL application and run, I get this error:

> The procedure entry point glMap1f could not be located in the dynamic link library OPENGL32.dll

This is strange because I have a dummy function in my code for every OpenGL call, including this one. In my header file I have:

```
void __declspec(dllexport) glMap1f (GLenum target, GLfloat u1, GLfloat u2, GLint stride, GLint order, const GLfloat *points);
```

and in the source file:

```
void  glMap1f (GLenum target, GLfloat u1, GLfloat u2, GLint stride, GLint order, const GLfloat *points){}
```

And I'm pretty sure that the compiler isn't optimizing it out, because looking at the DLL in a text editor, I can find the text "glMap1f".

What could be causing this? Also, I'm not really sure how to get visual studio to debug a DLL that overrides an actual system DLL so I wasn't able to get any more information.

Comment: Use Dependency Walker to find out what your DLL's exports are really named.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need `extern "C"` in front of your declaration of glMap1f to prevent the compiler using name mangling on it.

Comment: In addition to that you should also make sure that the export ordinal numbers to match. Little known fact that you can request symbols from a DLL not just by a string but also by a numeric value.